# Prove that $\int_{0}^{1}| f'(x)|^3dx \ge (\frac{128}{3 \pi } )^2.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function and $$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{1} xf(x)\,dx=1$$ Prove that $\int_{0}^{1}| f'(x)|^3\,dx \ge  (\frac{128}{3 \pi } )^2$. I know that $$1=\int_0^1 x(1-x) f'(x)\,dx\leq \left(\int_0^1 (x(1-x))^{3/2}\,dx\right)^{2/3} \left(\int_0^1 |f'(x)|^3\,dx\right)^{1/3}$$

Comment: If you've already proven that last inequality, why not just evaluate $\int_0^1 (x(1-x))^{3/2}\,\mathrm{d}x$ and isolate $\int_0^1 \lvert f'(x)\rvert^3\,\mathrm{d}x$?

Answer (score 0):

This is usage of [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

$B(5/2,5/2)=\int_{0}^{1}x^{\frac{3}{2}}(1-x)^{\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{3\pi}{128}$